# Which percentage of miners are using ASICs vs GPUs or FPGA? Is it possible to know?

Tags: network, energy-consumption

One of the common arguments against Bitcoin is the energy consumed by the network. The total hash-power of the network can be obtained fairly easily, but I'd like to estimate how much of that is due to ASIC, how much to FPGAs and how much to GPUs (if anybody's still using them).

If there were a way to separate the population of different ASICs themselves, a much better estimate could be made about the total power consumed by the network.

Any ideas??